# How to evaluate comments in php?

Tags: php, doctrine, comments, doctrine-odm

How is it possible, to evaluate commands in php like Doctrine?

If I write this, Doctrine can handle it somehow, but I have no idea how:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", name="title")
 * @var string
 */
private $title;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine uses [Doctrine Annotations](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations) library. Under the hood it uses reflection to get the comments and [parses](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php) them.

If you want to implement full fledged annotation support in your project then it's the easiest to use this library, otherwise you can try to parse doc comments by yourself.